# Can I pass a dictionary object to Restler?

Tags: php, restler

I know I can specify 'array' as the type for arrays, but what do I use when I want to pass in a dictionary type to a method using Restler 3?

The whole 'outer' block passed to the POST method is of course a dictionary type, but now I want one of the parameters to be a dictionary type as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Dictionary in Request

Define a dictionary as a class with public properties

```
class Object
{
    public $property = 'value';

    /** 
     * @var string {@required false} 
     */
    public $optional = 'value';

    //add more properties here
}
```

Let your api method use it as one of its parameters

```
class Api
{
    public function method(Object $obj, $name)
    {
        //use $obj->property here
    }
}
```

---

### Dictionary in Response

You can use an associative array (array with string indexes) or an instance of `stdClass` for this purpose

```
return array {

    'name' => 'Gargoyle'
    'object' => array {
        'property' => 'value'
    }

};
```

or

```
$r = new stdClass();
$r->name = 'Gargoyle';
$r->object = new stdClass();
$r->object->property = 'value';
return $r;
```

Both result in an JSON object output

Comment: I know how to create an assoc array in PHP itself, but I am trying to figure out how to make it work with the restler REST api.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you want! Are you trying to pass a dictionary as one of the properties for an API Method and wondering how you will receive it?

Comment: Correct.  I'm not sure what to put after the @param in the method comment.

Comment: I have updated the answer for you! If you need a practical example see http://restler3.luracast.com/examples/_016_forms/readme.html

Comment: @Gargoyle is that the answer you are looking for?

Comment: So it looks like that would work as long as I have a defined 'entity' that I'm passing in and can define something like the Address class directly.

Comment: Yes, Restler instantiates the entity (Class) and pre populates the properties for you

Comment: Is there a way to make the properties not required?  When I pass class into a patch method, for example, I might have only filled out some of the fields.  I don't want to make the caller have to explicitly set everything they aren't updating to NULL, for example.

Comment: Updated the example to include a optional parameter

Comment: I noticed if I do the @var comment on one line like you do, I get "Unsupported operand types in .../Routes.php on line 559".  Making it the multiline format doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: @Gargoyle Thanks for the comment about a single line var - I would have never figured that our